# How to get a newly created EXT4 filesystem to finish writing the index node immediatly?

Tags: hard-drive, ext4, spindown

I newly created an ext4 1TB partition, but I could not spin down the Hard disk on which the partition is mounted without unmounting first because the disk is having some activity every about 2s. I did some searching on the internet and found about the ext4lazyinit which is slowly creating the "index node" on the partition. Can I force it to create the node immediately instead of gradually over a long time?

According to the hard disk activity tool, the hard disk is writing 4 MiB at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: unmount the filesystem and remount it temporally adding `-o init_itable=0` to force ext4lazyinit to work faster on completing its job.